# Accessing Pdf File Names from Downloads using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, storage

I am trying to create a recycler View where the fileNames of pdf files are shown and the pdf icon but i am not able to do so, I am new to kotlin and I am learning how to implement it, for android 11 upwards.

Here is my code
My Document.kt class

```
`package com.example.securityapps

import PDFADAPTER
import android.Manifest
import android.R.attr.mimeType
import android.content.ContentUris
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor.UncaughtThrowableStrategy.LOG
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.log
import java.io.File


class Documents : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
   //declare a variable for Transfer button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_documents)
        Log.println(Log.DEBUG,"this","Hello")
        // find Transfer button by id


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_pdf)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, DOCUMENT_COLUMN_COUNT)

        // Check if permission is granted
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            // Request permission if not granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE
            )
        } else {
            // Permission granted, load documents from gallery
            val documentPathList = getDocumentsFromDownloads()
              Log.println(Log.VERBOSE ,"moon",documentPathList.toString())
            val adapter = PDFADAPTER()
            adapter.PdfConvertor(this, documentPathList.map { File(it) })
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted, load documents from gallery
                val documentPathList = getDocumentsFromDownloads()

                val adapter = PDFADAPTER()
                adapter.PdfConvertor(this, documentPathList.map { File(it) })
                recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                recyclerView.adapter = adapter
Log.println(Log.DEBUG,"this_is_not_working",documentPathList.toString())
                // Set visibility of Transfer button if at least one document is checked



            } else {
                // Permission denied
                // Show an error message or do nothing
                Log.println(Log.DEBUG,"permission","permission denied");
            }
        }
    }
    private fun getDocumentsFromDownloads(): List<String> {
        val documentList = mutableListOf<String>()

        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Downloads._ID,
            MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Downloads.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Downloads.SIZE,
            MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH
        )

        val selection = "${MediaStore.Downloads.MIME_TYPE} = ? AND ${MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH} LIKE ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf("application/pdf", "%Download%")

        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null
        )

        cursor?.use {
            val idCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads._ID)
            val nameCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val addedCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.DATE_ADDED)
            val sizeCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.SIZE)
            val pathCol = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Downloads.RELATIVE_PATH)

            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val fileId = cursor.getLong(idCol)
                val fileUri: Uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, fileId)
                val fileName = cursor.getString(nameCol)
                val dateAdded = cursor.getLong(addedCol)
                val size = cursor.getLong(sizeCol)
                val relativePath = cursor.getString(pathCol)
                val fullPath = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path}/$relativePath/$fileName"
                documentList.add(fullPath)

            }
        }

        return documentList
    }




    companion object
    {
        private const val DOCUMENT_COLUMN_COUNT = 2
        private const val READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    }
}`
```

My PdfAdapter.kt class
`

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.securityapps.R
import com.example.securityapps.Recycler_Adapter
import java.io.File

class PDFADAPTER() :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PDFADAPTER.ViewHolder>() {
    private var context: Context? = null
    private lateinit var pdfFiles: List<File>

    fun PdfConvertor(context: Context, pdfFiles: List<File>) {
        this.context = context
        this.pdfFiles = pdfFiles
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val pdfCardView: CardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_cardView)
        val pdfImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_image)
        val pdfName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_name)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.activity_documents, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return pdfFiles.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val pdfFile = pdfFiles[position]
        holder.pdfName.text = pdfFile.nameWithoutExtension
        holder.pdfCardView.setOnClickListener {
            // TODO: handle click event
        }
    }
}
```

`
and the pdf_card_view.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/pdf_cardView"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/linear_Pdf"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pdf_image"
            android:layout_width="299dp"
            android:layout_height="133dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/pdf_icons" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pdf_name"
            android:layout_width="384dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />



    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>`
```

and the activity.xml file

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_pdf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/airdrop_button"

        android:layout_width="406dp"
        android:layout_height="98dp"

        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="572dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="61dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:text="@string/transfer" />

</RelativeLayout>
```